# using sardine for accessing a sharepoint website from a java application

Tags: java, sharepoint, sardine

```
SardineFactory.begin(username, password);
sardine.exists("http://mydomain.sharepoint.com/TeamSite/Documents");
```

I thought [sardine](http://code.google.com/p/sardine/) can login auto but it returns 403 error.

I didn't use sardine and SharePoint Online before.

[Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using Claims-Based Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147177.aspx)

I know i should do something else but don't know how.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: What kind of authentication protocol is your SharePoint using? Any Kerberos or something?

Answer (score 0):

The SharePoint is most likely using Claims-Based Authentication, which is a nightmare to negotiate and authenticate through using Java.

Most solutions I've seen from others (although I have not yet seen a working demo) claim you have to use a .NET "mediator" in a non-CBA environment that your Java app can communicate with, and the "mediator" will in turn more easily get through the CBA authentication routine (keeping things within the .NET family).

Being stubborn, I am working on a pure Java solution and will post if I ever get it working.